# How can I source a bash script containing BASH_SOURCE from zsh shell?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I have a bash script that looks like this:

```
...
SOME_VARIABLE=$(readlink -f $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}))
export SOME_VARIABLE
...
```

I need to source it from a zsh shell as I need to have all the environment variables it defines.

The issue is that I get this error message because of BASH_SOURCE:

```
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
readlink: missing operand
Try 'readlink --help' for more information.
Invalid location:
```

**Constraints**: I cannot modify the script.

**Question**: Can I source a bash script containing BASH_SOURCE from zsh?

Comment: Source it from a `bash` shell, then start the `zsh` shell.

Comment: `. <(awk '{gsub(/\${BASH_SOURCE\[0\]}/, FILENAME); print}' /path/to/the/bash/script)`

Comment: @mosvy that works for me, I would mark it as accepted if it was an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 7):

Instead of doing `. /path/to/that/script.bash`, do:

```
BASH_SOURCE=/path/to/that/script.bash emulate ksh -c '. "$BASH_SOURCE"'
```

`emulate ksh -c '...'` runs the code in `ksh` emulation (so that for instance, array indices start at 0 like in bash) and also makes sure all functions defined within inherit that emulation mode.

`$BASH_SOURCE` in `bash` refers to the file being sourced, so we preseed that variable with the path of the script.

The `zsh` equivalent of that `bash` code would be:

```
export SOME_VARIABLE=$0:h:P
```

(`:h` giving the *head* like in csh (the equivalent of `dirname`), and `:P` the equivalent of GNU `readlink -f`).

In any case, that

```
SOME_VARIABLE=$(readlink -f $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}))
```

Code is incorrect in `bash` where you'd need:

```
SOME_VARIABLE=$(
  readlink -f -- "$(dirname -- "$BASH_SOURCE")"
)
```

And note that even then it wouldn't work if the dirname of `$BASH_SOURCE` ended in newline characters before or after `readlink -f`.

Answer (score 0):

Cool; I had a similar issue -- which I solved by other means, after giving it a second thought --, but this question is quite interesting actually. And the solution quite elegant (I think so).

The main/real question (AFAIU) is:

> I need to source it from a zsh shell as I need to have all the environment variables it defines.

, where *it* is the Bash script.

The fact that the script uses `BASH_SOURCE` is actually secondary; The script *is* Bash, period. We may be consider it a "black-box", and all we wanna do is to figure out what variables are being defined (or modified) there.

- **The script has to be source'd *on* Bash.**

That being said, what we have to do is to (from inside a Bash interpreter)

1. *buffer the initial state* of the environment,
2. *source* the script,
3. *buffer the afterwards state* of the environment,
4. *diff* the buffers.

And you/we should have the new/modified variables printed out.

The proposed **SOLUTION** -- the above steps -- look like:

```bsh
% bash -c 'buf1=$(env|sort) && source bashrc && buf2=$(env|sort) && diff <(echo "$buf1") <(echo "$buf2")'
```

, where `bashrc` is the name of the supposed script.

> Notice that this actually works for *any* shell (zsh, csh, ksh, etc), as long as Bash is installed and the version is compatible with the script (most likely to happen, but worth noting).

As an **EXAMPLE**, I have here the following script -- I'm calling it `bashrc`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
HERE=$(cd `dirname $BASH_SOURCE`; pwd)
PATH="${HERE}/bin:$PATH"
export HERE
export PATH
```

, which defines a new variable -- `$HERE` -- and a modifies an existing one -- `$PATH`. I put this script in my `/tmp` directory. The above command gives me:

```
6a7
> HERE=/tmp
15c16
< PATH=/Users/chbrandt/bin/links:/Users/chbrandt/bin/links:/Users/chbrandt/bin/links:/opt/miniconda3/bin:/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
---
> PATH=/tmp/bin:/Users/chbrandt/bin/links:/Users/chbrandt/bin/links:/Users/chbrandt/bin/links:/opt/miniconda3/bin:/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Sweet, isn't it? ...Now you do some post-proc (inside your zsh, for instance) to handle the symbols and whatever else and that's it ;)